# Anchor links need two clicks to go to the right section

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tags, anchor

So I have a table of contents section which I want to open and close during the hovering process. The problem is that I need to click to a link in that table of contents twice to make it go to the right section. All corresponding IDs in the anchor tags are okay. It's a wordpress site. Browser Chrome.

Could it be that the script is interfering and how can I correct it?

Here's the javascript I used:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $( '.tableofcontents' ).hover(function() {
        $( this ).children( 'h5' ).trigger( 'click' );
     });
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change "hover" function to "mouseenter"

```js
$( '.tableofcontents' ).on('mouseenter', function() {
    $( this ).children( 'h5' ).trigger( 'click' );
});
```

Comment: or mouseover, maybe

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I have replaced it, but I have the same problem. Maybe it's not a script issue? No idea